Implement C#-style Linq in C++
Here is the code
template <typename Source, typename Pred>
struct Selected
{
    using ElemInput = typename Source::Elem;

    static typename ElemInput GetElemInput();
    static Pred GetPred();
    using Elem = decltype(GetPred()(GetElemInput()));

    Selected(Source&& input, Pred pred) : mInput(input), mPred(pred) {}

    bool MoveNext() { return mInput.MoveNext(); }
    Elem Current() const { return mPred(mInput.Current()); }

    bool mStarted = false;
    Source mInput;
    Pred mPred;
};

template <typename Source, typename Pred>
struct Filtered
{
    using Elem = typename Source::Elem;

    Filtered(Source&& input, Pred pred) : mInput(input), mPred(pred) {}

    bool MoveNext() 
    { 
        while (mInput.MoveNext())
        {
            if (mPred(mInput.Current()))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    Elem Current() const { return mInput.Current(); }

    Source mInput;
    Pred mPred;
};

template <typename Container>
struct Enumerable
{
    using Elem = typename Container::value_type;
    using Iter = typename Container::const_iterator;

    Enumerable(const Container& container) : mBegin(container.begin()), mEnd(container.end()) {}

    bool MoveNext() 
    {
        mStarted ? (++mBegin, true) : (mStarted = true);
        return mBegin != mEnd;
    }
    Elem Current() const { return *mBegin; }
    
    bool mStarted = false;
    Iter mBegin, mEnd;
};

template <typename Source, typename Pred>
Selected<Source, Pred> Select(Source&& input, Pred fun)
{
    return Selected<Source, Pred>(std::forward<Source>(input), fun);
}

template <typename Source, typename Pred>
Filtered<Source, Pred> Where(Source&& input, Pred fun)
{
    return Filtered<Source, Pred>(std::forward<Source>(input), fun);
}

template <typename Source>
std::vector<typename Source::Elem> ToVector(Source&& input)
{
    std::vector<typename Source::Elem> result;
    while (input.MoveNext())
    {
        result.push_back(input.Current());
    }
    return result;
}

void Test()
{
    std::vector<int> input = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    auto result = ToVector( // this call seems hard to understand
        Select(
            Where(
                Select(
                    Enumerable(input),
                    [](auto e) { return e + 10; }
                ),
                [](auto e) { return e % 3 == 0; }
            ),
            [](auto e) { return std::to_string(e); }
        )
    );

    for (auto e : result)
    {
        std::cout << e << std::endl;
    }
}

The stacked function call ToVector(Select(Where(/*...*/))) is hard to understand. So my question is, is there a way to support such function call like this:
auto result = Enumerable(input)
    .Select([](auto e) { return e + 10; })
    .Where([](auto e) { return e % 3 == 0; })
    .Select([](auto e) { return std::to_string(e); })
    .ToVector();

Actually I tried to implement all operations (Select/Where) in each intermediate result type (struct Selected/struct Filtered), but this approach ends up with each result type definition depends on all other kinds of result type, thus ends up with this error:

struct Filtered undefined in Selected::Where function.


Use the ranges library
What you have implemented and tried implementing is already in the standard library since C++20, as part of the ranges library. In particular:

Enumerable isn't necessary. It's just a convenience wrapper, but you can use the regular iterator functionality of containers directly. However, the equivalent is std::views::all().
Select() is availble in C++20 as std::views::transform().
Filter() is available in C++20 as std::views::filter().
ToVector() hardcodes the output type to std::vector, but in C++23 there is the much more flexible std::ranges::to().

Your Test() function can be written like so:
void Test()
{
    std::vector<int> input = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    auto result = std::ranges::to<std::vector>(
        std::views::transform(
            std::views::filter(
                std::views::transform(
                    input,
                    [](auto e) { return e + 10; }
                ),
                [](auto e) { return e % 3 == 0; }
            ),
            [](auto e) { return std::to_string(e); }
        )
    );

    for (auto e : result)
    {
        std::cout << e << '\n';
    }
}

You can also write this more compactly by using the pipeline operator:
void Test()
{
    std::vector<int> input = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    auto result = input
                | std::views::transform([](auto e) { return e + 10; })
                | std::views::filter   ([](auto e) { return e % 3 == 0; })
                | std::views::transform([](auto e) { return std::to_string(e); })
                | std::ranges::to<std::vector>();

    for (auto e : result)
    {
        std::cout << e << '\n';
    }
}

The pipeline operator makes it possible to compose actions on ranges and views without having to add all possible operations as member functions to each view/range class.
Issues with your version
The ranges library is already quite extensive, and can do much more than selecting, filtering and converting to a vector. However, there are some other issues with your code:

You are not providing the standard iterator API, meaning you can't write something like for (auto element: Select(input, function)) {…}. Only after converting to a vector can the normal STL functions be used on the result.
You are not constraining the allowed parameter types, which will result in hard to read error messages if your classes are constructed incorrectly. Using concepts would help.
You are passing elements by value. While that is relatively safe, it might be inefficient, and it also prevents working with elements that are non-copyable.
Don't copy element types blindly. Consider this code:
std::array<const int, 6> input = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
auto result = ToVector(Enumerable(input));

This won't compile because you can't create a std::vector<const int>. You probably should use something like std::remove_cvref on the element type before using it in the output type.

